# Is "Merged in" a commit message created by bitbucket, or git?

Tags: git, bitbucket, commit-message

The style guide "How to Write a Git Commit Message" section [5. Use the imperative mood in the subject line](http://chris.beams.io/posts/git-commit/#imperative) states that git itself uses the imperative mood:

> The imperative can sound a little rude; that's why we don't often use it. But it's perfect for git commit subject lines. One reason for this is that git itself uses the imperative whenever it creates a commit on your behalf.
>
> For example, the default message created when using git merge reads:
>
> `Merge branch 'myfeature'`
>
> And when using git revert:
>
> `Revert "Add the thing with the stuff"`
>
> `This reverts commit cc87791524aedd593cff5a74532befe7ab69ce9d.`
>
> Or when
>   clicking the "Merge" button on a GitHub pull request:
>
> `Merge pull request #123 from someuser/somebranch`

However, on a git repository on bitbucket, I encounter the indicative mood:

> Merged in feature/123 (pull request #1234)

Is this a message created by bitbucket as opposed to git?

Comment: Can you provide some documentation directly from Git which says that the imperative mood is used in commits?  I could argue that `Merge branch 'myfeature'` is actually short for `Merge of branch 'myfeature'`.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: It comes from Git's own SubmittingPatches documentation: https://github.com/git/git/blob/bca181109d6f054d525c71a84963bbdc1f0c40bf/Documentation/SubmittingPatches#L112

Comment: `git` itself doesn't have the concept of pull requests, so that leaves whatever manages the pull requests as the only possible culprit.

Comment: Part of the commit message is from the title of the pull request, which can be changed on the bitbucket website, so that'd suggest that bitbucket is the main generator of the merge commit message.

Comment: Have raised a suggestion on BitBucket's JIRA: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BSERV-8427

Comment: For the record, here's Ric's ticket on the Bitbucket Cloud bugtracker: https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/12472/
Go vote for it if you're annoyed by the "Merged in" as well :)

Answer (score 3):

From looking at my team's branch, when someone merges their own PR, you see

**"Merge branch 'branchName' of bitbucket.org..."**.

When someone merges someone else's PR, you see

**"Merged in teamName/repositoryName/branchName"**